# How is "partial" password reuse determined?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

How do environments like Active Directory determine if you reuse parts of previous passwords in a new password? I understand that it keeps a list of your last passwords, hashed. But how do they determine if I reuse parts of a last password only?
I thought that the passwords were never decrypted, and could not be viewed.

I know how to determine how alike two strings are, but how is this done in a secure way, instead of using plaintext passwords?

I might be misunderstanding this, but I couldn't find any conclusive information

Comment: *"use a specific word (like the company name)"* - this has nothing to do with your title question of partial password _reuse_. And the answer to this part is simple - the password is checked against some predefined  word lists when setting it or when entering it, because it is available in clear there. I've therefore removed this part from your question and restricted it to the _reuse_ part as seen in the title.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but I think you created a new problem. Is it true that AD can determine if someone re-used part of a previous password if they reused string is not in the plaintext list of string fragments to reject?

Comment: So, now we need details. Sebastian, did you mean that AD can detect ***reuse*** of parts of your previous passwords or ***use*** of certain words?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough in my question. What I meant was, if I use a specific word in my previous passwords (for example, "Copenhagen123", "Copenhagen456", etc) putting aside that they are not very secure, could AD detect that I use the word "Copenhagen" often, and how?